# Parsing file names to get python package names consistently

Tags: shell, awk, sed

Need some scripting help. Here is the problem. I have a set of python packages (files)

```
beautifulsoup4-4.12.2-py3-none-any.whl
certifi-2023.7.22-py3-none-any.whl
charset_normalizer-3.3.1-cp311-cp311-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl
google-3.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
idna-3.4-py3-none-any.whl
protobuf3-0.2.1.tar.gz
protobuf-3.19.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl
proton-0.9.1.tar.gz
python-qpid-proton-0.38.0.tar.gz
redis-4.5.5-py3-none-any.whl
requests-2.31.0-py3-none-any.whl
robotframework-6.1.1-py3-none-any.whl
robotframework_requests-0.9.1-py3-none-any.whl
robotframework-run-keyword-async-1.0.8.tar.gz
soupsieve-2.5-py3-none-any.whl
urllib3-2.0.7-py3-none-any.whl
```

I need to parse each file name to get the package name and its version. I have some working while others fail. Basically the list above should find this for the name and version of each.

```
beautifulsoup4                    4.12.2
certifi                           2023.7.22
charset-normalizer                3.3.1
google                            3.0.0
idna                              3.4
protobuf3                         0.2.1
protobuf                          3.19.6
proton                            0.9.1
python-qpid-proton                0.38.0
redis                             4.5.5
requests                          2.31.0
robotframework                    6.1.1
robotframework-requests           0.9.1
robotframework-run-keyword-async  1.0.8
soupsieve                         2.5
urllib3                           2.0.7
```

I've tried cut, grep, sed, and awk to get this working but the numbers appearing in names, multi-digit versions, inconsistency of pattern, cause one or the other methods to fail. You'll also notice that charset and robotframework-requests change _ to a - but those cases I'm hoping are less frequent and I can work around that when it happens.

I'm stuck on how to make this work. Any ideas. Here is my current script logic (fullName is the file name listed above) but if fails for certifi, charset-normalizer, idna, soupsieve, and robotframework-requests.

```
version=`echo "$fullName" | sed -nre 's/^[^0-9]*(([0-9]+\.)*[0-9]+).*/\1/p'`
artifactId=`echo "$fullName" | sed -r "s/-${version}.*//g"`
```

Specifically for the current script for the ones that don't work build the artifact and version as:

```
beautifulsoup4                  4
protobuf3-0.2.1.tar.gz          3
urllib3-2.0.7-py3-none-any.whl  3
```

If anyone has a good way to parse the artifactId/version with regex or any other bash scripting method I'm open to try anything.

Thanks

Comment: This gets me a little closer (edited the above) for finding and parsing out the version.  It only fails when a number appears in the file name.    version=`echo "$fullName" | sed -nre 's/^[^0-9]*(([0-9]+\.)*[0-9]+).*/\1/p'`

Comment: Do you REALLY want to turn `charset_normalizer` into `charset-normalizer` and `robotframework_requests` into `robotframework-requests`? If not then please [edit] your example to fix it.

Comment: Since I have to pass this to another tool I have to change those because of the product maintainers delivered their source package.  If you look at Charset (https://github.com/Ousret/charset_normalizer/releases/tag/3.3.1)  you'll notice they are very inconsistent in their naming.  Since the tool parsing the charset-normalizer-3.3.1.tar.gz but  Python pulls down the charset_normalizer-3.3.1-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl it forces me to have to convert to the source naming. So while I would love to not have to convert, I can't

Comment: The reasoning doesn't matter, just your requirements and example. I see you accepted an answer that doesn't convert `charset_normalizer` into `charset-normalizer` so apparently for the purposes of this question (which is all that matters here) you don't need that after all.

Comment: I see you're using `sed -r` - `-r` is the equivalent of `-E` for old versions of GNU sed, current versions of GNU sed and BSD sed both support `-E` so you should use that as it's more portable and it's consistent with `grep -E`.

Comment: Regarding ```version=`echo "$fullName" | sed -nre 's/^[^0-9]*(([0-9]+\.)*[0-9]+).*/\1/p'` ``` - backticks have been obsolete for several years now in favor of `$(...)`, see [the POSIX standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xcu_chap02.html#tag_23_02_06_03), so you should do ```version=$(echo "$fullName" | sed -nre 's/^[^0-9]*(([0-9]+\.)*[0-9]+).*/\1/p') ``` instead but of course you should really be using `printf` instead of `echo` for robustness and portability and you don't need echo/printf or sed anyway as bash could do this with builtins (google `BASH_REMATCH`).

Comment: Good to know...been scripting since the 90 so I'm a bit dated on my syntax :)

Comment: I've been scripting since 82 - tell me about it :-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `sed` you could use 2 capture groups and capture and number format after the last occurrence of `-` followed by either `-` or `.`

If there has to be at least a single dot in the version, you can change `(\.[0-9]+)*` to `(\.[0-9]+)+`

```
sed -E 's/^(.*)-([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)*)[.-].*/\1 \2/' file | column -t
```

Output

```
beautifulsoup4                    4.12.2
certifi                           2023.7.22
charset_normalizer                3.3.1
google                            3.0.0
idna                              3.4
protobuf3                         0.2.1
protobuf                          3.19.6
proton                            0.9.1
python-qpid-proton                0.38.0
redis                             4.5.5
requests                          2.31.0
robotframework                    6.1.1
robotframework_requests           0.9.1
robotframework-run-keyword-async  1.0.8
soupsieve                         2.5
urllib3                           2.0.7
```

Comment: This one worked with a slight mode. I'm not trying to put out the columns represented in my posted.  I am actually just trying to set a version variable and using find to traverse a directory tree.  So this solution using the following got me a consistent set.  Thank you           version=`echo "$fullName" | sed -E "s/^(.*)-([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)*)[.-].*/\2/"`

Answer (score 3):

If the input was a list of names stored in a file or coming in from a pipe then a `sed` or `awk` solution would be the better approach as that'd be far more efficient than a shell loop reading the input (see [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)), but given the input is actually just 1 string stored in a variable, bash builtins are the better approach as that'd be more efficient than spawning a subshell to call echo+sed in a pipe.

So, to regexp-match a variable named `fullName`s contents and save just the parts you want in a variable named `version` after converting `_`s to `-`s in the first capture group, just using bash builtins would be:

```
[[ $fullName =~ ^(.*)-([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)*) ]] &&
    printf -v version '%s\t%s\n' "${BASH_REMATCH[1]//_/-}" "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
```

Using a shell loop just to populate `fullName` from your provided sample input so we can demonstrate (again, you would not write a shell loop just to manipulate text):

```
$ while IFS= read -r fullName; do
    [[ $fullName =~ ^(.*)-([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)*) ]] &&
        printf '%s\t%s\n' "${BASH_REMATCH[1]//_/-}" "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
  done < file  | column -t
beautifulsoup4                    4.12.2
certifi                           2023.7.22
charset-normalizer                3.3.1
google                            3.0.0
idna                              3.4
protobuf3                         0.2.1
protobuf                          3.19.6
proton                            0.9.1
python-qpid-proton                0.38.0
redis                             4.5.5
requests                          2.31.0
robotframework                    6.1.1
robotframework-requests           0.9.1
robotframework-run-keyword-async  1.0.8
soupsieve                         2.5
urllib3                           2.0.7
```

See:

- [Regexp
  Matching with `BASH_REMATCH`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Conditional-Constructs)
- [Parameter
  Substitution with `${var//old/new}`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)

Answer (score 2):

If you have only 1 Input_file and you want to get values out of it then try following. Written and tested in GNU `awk`. Written and tested with shown samples Only.

```
awk '
match($0,/^(.*)-([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)*)[.-].*/,arr){
  print arr[1]"\t"arr[2]
}
' packagesFile.txt  | column -t
```

Answer (score 0):

> Any ideas.

If you are okay with using external python package you might use [wheel-filename](https://pypi.org/project/wheel-filename/) for wheel (*.whl) files, first install it by doing

```
python3 -m pip install wheel-filename
```

then you might use it following way, let say you have `list.txt` as follows

```
beautifulsoup4-4.12.2-py3-none-any.whl
certifi-2023.7.22-py3-none-any.whl
charset_normalizer-3.3.1-cp311-cp311-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl
google-3.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
idna-3.4-py3-none-any.whl
protobuf3-0.2.1.tar.gz
protobuf-3.19.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl
proton-0.9.1.tar.gz
python-qpid-proton-0.38.0.tar.gz
redis-4.5.5-py3-none-any.whl
requests-2.31.0-py3-none-any.whl
robotframework-6.1.1-py3-none-any.whl
robotframework_requests-0.9.1-py3-none-any.whl
robotframework-run-keyword-async-1.0.8.tar.gz
soupsieve-2.5-py3-none-any.whl
urllib3-2.0.7-py3-none-any.whl
```

create nameparser.py with following content

```
from wheel_filename import parse_wheel_filename
with open("list.txt", "r") as f:
    filenames = [i.rstrip() for i in f.readlines()]  # strip trailing newlines
for fname in filenames:
    if fname.endswith("whl"):
        pwf = parse_wheel_filename(fname)
        print(pwf.project, pwf.version)
    else:
        print("Non-wheel file", fname)
```

and do `python3 nameparser.py` to get following output

```
beautifulsoup4 4.12.2
certifi 2023.7.22
charset_normalizer 3.3.1
google 3.0.0
idna 3.4
Non-wheel file protobuf3-0.2.1.tar.gz
protobuf 3.19.6
Non-wheel file proton-0.9.1.tar.gz
Non-wheel file python-qpid-proton-0.38.0.tar.gz
redis 4.5.5
requests 2.31.0
robotframework 6.1.1
robotframework_requests 0.9.1
Non-wheel file robotframework-run-keyword-async-1.0.8.tar.gz
soupsieve 2.5
urllib3 2.0.7
```

If you want to know more about naming wheel files read [PEP 427](https://peps.python.org/pep-0427/).